# SQLSTATE[22023]: Invalid parameter value: 3037 Invalid GIS data provided to function mbrcontains

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

(Hi !)
I'm not very good at SQL and I didn't find any solution on internet, I have the following error (with Symfony4)

> SQLSTATE[22023]: Invalid parameter value: 3037 Invalid GIS data provided to function mbrcontains.

My request is here :

`$sql = '
        SELECT * FROM rent_release r
        WHERE CONTAINS("date", :yearRequested)
        ';`

date is defined later because it's how it works with doctrine:
 `$stmt->execute(['yearRequested' => $year]);`

Does anyone know what's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone helped me on Symfony slack

`` SELECT * FROM rent_release r WHERE YEAR(`date`) = :yearRequested ``